# Where to modify Bats (Bash Automated Testing System) Variables

Tags: bash, bats-core

I'm using Bats (Bash Automated Testing System) to automate some bash unit testing. Some of these bash tests might hang forever, so I want some global timeout on my tests. I want to achieve this in my `.bats` file.

I'm trying set a timeout on all of my tests in my `.bats` file. I read the documentation provided by the bats wiki and found the `$BATS_TEST_TIMEOUT` variable, which is exactly what I need. I set the variable in my `setup_file()` as follows:

```
setup_file(){
    BATS_TEST_TIMEOUT=5
}

@test "Dummy Loop test" {
    ./loop.sh
}
```

but my dummy infinite loop test still ran forever. Blocked by this, I tried setting other variables, like $BATS_TEST_RETRIES, and that didn't work either. I've drawn the conclusion that I must be setting them incorrectly somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those variables must be set in the environment of the `bats` process itself, so you can:

```
export BATS_TEST_TIMEOUT=5
bats .
```

Or:

```
BATS_TEST_TIMEOUT=5 bats .
```

Etc.

For example, given this test in `mytest.bats`:

```
@test "Dummy sleep test" {
    sleep 30
}
```

If I run `bats` like this:

```
BATS_TEST_TIMEOUT=5 bats .
```

I see:

```
./mytest.bats
 ✗ Dummy sleep test [timeout: 5s]
   (in test file ./mytest.bats, line 6)
     `sleep 30' failed due to timeout
   Terminated

1 test, 0 failures, 1 timed out
```

If you don't want to have to set this every time, add some sort of `run-tests.sh` script to your project that sets whatever variables you want and then calls `bats`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still isn't working for me. I tried both exporting the timeout and typing it inline, neither produced the desired timeout behavior, even when I copied your dummy test. BATS_TEST_RETRIES didn't work with this method either. I appreicate your quick response though!

Comment: The output shown in this answer is verbatim from running these locally. I'll note that I have bats 1.9.0 installed, so double check what version you're running.

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I installed `bats` directly from the command line with apt-get, but after doing some digging, it seems like only bats 1.1 gets installed this way, even after updating my apt. When I installed from source, bats 1.9 gets installed, and your answer works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On top of @larsks' answer, I found that bats variables can indeed be set in the `setup_file()`, they just need to be exported also.

For example:

```bash
setup_file(){
    export BATS_TEST_TIMEOUT=5
}

@test "Dummy Loop" {
    ./dummy.sh # This will timeout after 5 seconds
}
```